# Instance Doesnt boot correctly, hangs on - "a start job is running for LSB: Raise network Interface.."

Tags: google-compute-engine, boot

My VM was shutdown due to end of Trial. However i have since made payment and started other instances. 
GCE UI shows this system as successfully booted, however looking at the serial port it shows the following (see image)
Any ideas how to fix this ?

Screenshot of Boot Error:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C2rN.png]

```
    [    6.895575] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
    [    6.951588] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
    [    6.993046] AVX version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
    [    6.996351] alg: No test for __gcm-aes-aesni (__driver-gcm-aes-aesni)
    [    7.001659] alg: No test for crc32 (crc32-pclmul)
    [  OK  ] Started LSB: start firewall.
    [***] A start job is running for LSB: Raise network interf...17s / no limit)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue...

Comment: I have tried "SysRq" Commands via GCE Serial Console but they don't seem to trigger/work as expected

Comment: Was this issue caused due to an operating system upgrade? If yes, how was the OS upgraded? I have found [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/RGPdlGf3Qi8) thread where user had the similar issue that might be useful.

Comment: Only update & upgrade had been run on the system. so no major version jump. I still have the VM powered down and looking for a fix. Big issue being GCE instance unable to drop to any kind of terminal to edit files

Comment: Are you able to run command through [interactive serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console)?If its not working, you can delete the instance by keeping your boot disk and try to debug the issue by attaching this disk to another working instance. The steps to do so are documented on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#pdboot).

Comment: Unable to run any commands through serical console. I have instead mounted the disk to another VM and extracted my data.